# Forcing an update of a property from within a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom control that is based on `RangeBase`.  In the control, I'm displaying a formatted version of the `Value`, like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
       AncestorType={x:Type local:NumericUpDownControl}}, Path=FormattedValue}" />
```

`FormattedValue` looks like this:

```
public string FormattedValue
{
    get { return Value.ToString(_format); }            
}
```

This all seems to work fine.  However, in the control, there is a button that increases the value of `Value`:

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Value += 0.5;            
}
```

The problem that I have is that the FormattedValue is never updated. I imagine that I need something akin to `RaisePropertyChanged` but from within the control. I tried adding a dummy set to `FormattedValue` but to no avail. How can I get this value to update on the screen?

Comment: Why cant you have FormattedValue as a Dependency Property?

Comment: Wouldn't that cause `FormattedValue` to available outside the control?  I don't want this.

Comment: Also, to the down-voter: why?

Comment: Does the `_format` field ever change?

Comment: Then bind directly to `Value` and do the formatting by means of the Label's `ContentStringFormat` property. Even better, use a TextBlock instead of a Label, and set the binding's `StringFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is, that you set the "Value" Property `Value += 0.5;` but you're binding to your "FormattedValue" property. So you Raise a "PropertyChanged" in the Setter of your "Value"  Property for your "FormattedValue" property an your code should work as desired.

**EDIT**

Better way then using an unnecessary additional property ("FormattedValue") is to use the ContentStringFormat property of the Label [ContentStringFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat(v=vs.110).aspx).